# Determining the age of a value

Tags: sql-server

How to determine the age of a value in SQL Server?

I have a daily list of rates charged to a given customer.  I need to figure out how long it's been since the rate has changed.

My query breaks down when a rate matches an earlier rate from a day other than the previous day.  You can see this on 11/9.  I want the rate there to be 1 but it matches the rate going back to 11/2 so the result is 8.

[Image of Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FZoO.png)

In SQL Server:

```
WITH sample AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
        ('2023-11-15', '94-69867', 66.99, 7),
        ('2023-11-14', '94-69867', 66.99, 6),
        ('2023-11-13', '94-69867', 66.99, 5),
        ('2023-11-12', '94-69867', 66.99, 4),
        ('2023-11-11', '94-69867', 66.99, 3),
        ('2023-11-10', '94-69867', 66.99, 2),
        ('2023-11-09', '94-69867', 66.99, 1),
        ('2023-11-08', '94-69867', 60.99, 4),
        ('2023-11-07', '94-69867', 60.99, 3),
        ('2023-11-06', '94-69867', 60.99, 2),
        ('2023-11-05', '94-69867', 60.99, 1),
        ('2023-11-04', '94-69867', 65.99, 2),
        ('2023-11-03', '94-69867', 65.99, 1),
        ('2023-11-02', '94-69867', 66.99, 7),
        ('2023-11-01', '94-69867', 66.99, 6),
        ('2023-10-31', '94-69867', 66.99, 5),
        ('2023-10-30', '94-69867', 66.99, 4),
        ('2023-10-29', '94-69867', 66.99, 3),
        ('2023-10-28', '94-69867', 66.99, 2),
        ('2023-10-27', '94-69867', 66.99, 1)
    ) AS t (BusinessDate, PropertyFolio, RateToPost, Desired)
)


SELECT *
    ,COUNT( RateToPost) OVER( PARTITION BY PropertyFolio, RateToPost ORDER BY PropertyFolio ASC, BusinessDate ASC) AS FixMe
FROM sample
ORDER BY BusinessDate DESC
```

Comment: So, what is your question here?

Comment: Please do not use images, use tabular markdown

Answer (score 1):

This is a kind of *gaps and islands* challenge.

One of a few possible ways to get your desired result is to first identify groups of consecutive values, then partition by this grouping to generate your result:

```
with groups as (
SELECT *, Row_Number() over (partition by PropertyFolio order by BusinessDate) 
        - Row_Number() over (partition by PropertyFolio, ratetopost order by BusinessDate) grp
FROM sample
)
select *, Row_Number() over (partition by PropertyFolio, grp order by BusinessDate) ExpectedResult
from groups;
```

See [working Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/f7pR1zvY)

Comment: Thanks Stu.  Almost there.  I found some issues when the rate changes on day 2.  I updated the sample data to include this.  10/29 should give me an age of 1 but I'm getting a 2.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mHyz-JGI)